# Glide Eror in Fragment with recyclerview

Tags: android

**i got msg error**
error: cannot access Fragment
Glide.with(this).from(TH).into(thumb);
^
class file for android.support.v4.app.Fragment not found

this is my adapter :

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < HomeAdapter.ViewHolder > {

    Context context;
    List < HomeClass > data;
    TextView Movie,
    desc,
    year,
    rating,
    genre;
    ImageView thumb;
    public HomeAdapter(List < HomeClass > data, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_rv, parent, false);


        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final HomeClass geter1 = data.get(position);
        String MN, DS, YR, RT, GN, TH;

        MN = geter1.getMoviename();
        DS = geter1.getDesc();
        YR = geter1.getYear();
        RT = geter1.getRating();
        GN = geter1.getGenre();
        TH = geter1.getImage_Movie();

        Movie.setText(MN);
        desc.setText(DS);
        year.setText(YR);
        rating.setText(RT);
        genre.setText(GN);

        Glide.with(this).from(TH).into(thumb);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Movie = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textMovieName);
            desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDescMovie);
            year = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textYearMovie);
            rating = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textRatingMovie);
            genre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textGenreMovie);
            thumb = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgMovie);
        }
    }
}
```

this is homefragment :

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
List<HomeClass> HClass;

String URL_Data="http://192.168.1.25/insoft/vod.php";
RequestQueue reqQue;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    recyclerView=v.findViewById(R.id.rvvod);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext()));
    HClass=new ArrayList<>();

    loadurl();
    return v;
}


private void loadurl() {
    JsonArrayRequest stringRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(URL_Data, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            getvalue(response);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    reqQue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    reqQue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getvalue(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        HomeClass movielist = new HomeClass();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            movielist.setMoviename(json.getString("Name"));
            movielist.setDesc(json.getString("Desc"));
            movielist.setGenre(json.getString("Genre"));
            movielist.setRating(json.getString("Rating"));
            movielist.setYear(json.getString("Year"));
            movielist.setImage_Movie(json.getString("Thumb"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HClass.add(movielist);
    }

    adapter = new HomeAdapter(HClass, getActivity());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

I try to show image from json to recyclerview, but got error.

how can solved that error?

Comment: use this  Glide.with(requireContext()).from(TH).into(thumb);

Comment: That need create new method

Comment: Glide.with(context).from(TH).into(thumb); try this

you added glide code in adapter class so use adapter class constructor context which you get from your Activity/Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

trace the error with following

First check id of RecyclerView

```
 @Override
public View onViewCreated(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            RecyclerView recyclerView= (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
            adapter listAdapter= new adapter();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());  //of v.getContext() or this
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        }
}
```

use context in recyclerView adapter

```
    this.context = context;
```

which above done perfectly.

then use context like Glide.with(context).

Comment: if recyclerView in fragment then use 

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(newLinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));            else if in activity user this in setLayoutManager              The adapter will use with(context) and your issue will resolved.

Comment: @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        recyclerView=v.findViewById(R.id.rvvod);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext()));
        HClass=new ArrayList<>();

        loadurl();
        return v;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final HomeClass geter1 =  data.get(position);
        String MN, DS, YR, RT, GN, TH;

        MN=geter1.getMoviename();
        DS=geter1.getDesc();
        YR=geter1.getYear();
        RT=geter1.getRating();
        GN=geter1.getGenre();
        TH=geter1.getImage_Movie();

        Movie.setText(MN);
        desc.setText(DS);
        year.setText(YR);
        rating.setText(RT);
        genre.setText(GN);
//change your code like this
        Glide.with(context).from(TH).into(thumb);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but didnt work. I got new error message

error: cannot access Fragment
        Glide.with(context).from(TH).into(thumb);
             ^
  class file for android.support.v4.app.Fragment not found

Comment: Error: cannot find symbol
        Glide.with(context).from(TH).into(thumb);
                           ^
  symbol:   method from(String)
  location: class RequestManager

Comment: share your app level gradle file

Answer (score 0):

which library do you import for fragment, AndroidX or support library ?
One more info, if you are using androidX for your project, you have to import androidX library